# Copy table with additional column

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

How to write a `PL/SQL` procedure that:

- Copies a table given by name into another given table by name (non-existing)
- Adds to the second table a new column `ts` filled with a current timestamp/datetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this.

```
create or replace procedure clone_table 
    ( p_copy_table in varchar2 
      , p_new_table in varchar2
      , p_inc_data in varchar2 := 'Y' )
is
    stmt varchar2(32767);
begin
    stmt := 'create table '|| p_new_table
                 || ' as select t.*, systimestamp as ts '
                 || ' from ' || p_copy_table || ' t';
    if p_inc_data != 'Y' then
        -- use a empty resultset to create an empty table
         stmt := stmt || ' where 1=0';
    end if;
    execute immediate stmt;
end;
```